# Do you get WvW Bonuses while in overflow maps?

Tags: guild-wars-2

While in a overflow map if you go to the WvW window to see the progress, you see the following message:

> WvW information is not visible from dungeons, instances, and overflow
>   maps. Travel to WvW to participate.

Do you still benefit from the WvW bonuses while in the overflow map even though you can't see it? Likewise I I assume it works the same for dungeons and instances so I would like to extend the question to them.

Comment: I know you get your bonus [when guesting](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/World_versus_World), but I'm not sure about when you're in Overflow. If I had to guess I'd say **yes**, but I'm uncertain.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not receive WvW bonuses in overflow maps.

Comment: You don't receive bonuses because overflow maps have people from all region servers in them.